# Is it acceptable if actual and formal parameters have the same name?

Tags: java

like this:

```
myMethod(first, second)

public void myMethod(int first, int second)
```

My teacher said it's preferred not to name them the same.  But I don't see the reason why? Is he wrong?

Comment: If we are discussing naming (the hardest thing in computer science), we need to see the real names and a bit more background. `first`, `second`, `myMethod` are terrible.

Comment: It is acceptable but in certain cases could create some confusion.

Comment: Your teacher said that why? Ask *him.* His 'preference' is news to me, but then I've only been doing this for 42 years. His preference is also meaningless. In many cases an actual argument is an expression, not a variable.

Comment: This seems fine to me.  If anything, providing some context or intent to the meaning of the names would be useful.

Comment: @tjg184: How can you say that? If the arguments are really called `first` and `second` the discussion stops right there.

Comment: The variables should describe what they both are in their own contexts (for example in the methods comtext it might be compared1 and compared2. But in the calling context it might be myPyjamas and myAuntsPyjamas. If they "mean" the same thing in both contexts then so be it

Comment: I agree that those particular names are bad, but I think in general it's good to make the names the same, as it makes things more clear.

Comment: @Thilo I guess I meant context in the grand scheme of the program.  Yes, I agree if they really are "first" and "second" then that makes sense.  This question is so subjective.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Make that an answer to collect your upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variables should describe what they both are in their own contexts.

For example in the methods context (formal parameters) it might be compared1 and compared2. But in the calling context (actual parameters) it might be `myPyjamas` and `myAuntsPyjamas`. If they "mean" the same thing in both contexts then so be it.

So in this example they may be different:

```
Fanciness comparativeFanciness= comparePyjamas(myPyjamas,myAuntsPyjamas);

public static Fanciness comparePyjamas(Pyjamas compared1,Pyjamas compared2){
     .....
}
```

<sup>for anyone wondering my pyjamas are very fancy</sup>

But in annother example they may be the same, because they both mean the same thing in both contexts:

```
setThrustDirection(thrustDirection);

public void setThrustDirection(Vector3d thrustDirection){
     .....
}
```

### caveat

It's often a good idea to avoid having a variable name the same as a field name (a.k.a. instance variable name) except in the constructor as you can end up [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the field (meaning you have to access the field as `this.name` and the variable as `name`)

Comment: +1. That's it exactly. If that means that the names should be the same, so be it. If that means that they should be different, so be it. All depends on what is most accurate and clear in the given program. Overly broad simplified rules don't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context. If there is a function to reverse a string

```
 def reverseString(theString)
```

theString is kind of ok for that function but unlikely to be a good variable name in the context of calling that function. If it's a person's name then something like when it is being called

```
 reverseString(firstName)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a possible shadowing problem.  If the class has an instance variable with the same  name as the parameter in the method definition, the coder needs to be careful and use **this.** when referring to the class level variable.  I've seen lots of students forget that and wonder why the code doesn't work.  I prefer unique names to prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of naming is to make the code more comprehensible, if your names do then they are more than acceptable, if they don't, maybe you was taught wrong...